# How to insert or ignore in Duckdb

Tags: python, pandas, database, insert, duckdb

I am inserting around 500K rows of data from a Pandas dataframe into a DuckDB database, but some of the data is duplicated and I have unique columns set up to improve query speed

When using

```
conn.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Main SELECT * FROM df')
```

I receive the error

```
duckdb.ParserException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "OR"
```

due to the IGNORE keyword not being supported in DuckDB.

Cleaning the data before insertion is not possible as the size of the data is very large and removing duplicates from the dataframe also does not work. How can I effectively insert this data into the database while avoiding duplicate records?

Comment: It's just Postgres notation, so use a [Postgres "UPSERT"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT).

Comment: I am using duckdb and UPSERT option is also not available in duckdb

Comment: See [this merge](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/5866).

Comment: Batch insertion is not supported in combination with ON CONFLICT (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Upsert support is added with the latest release(0.7.0) using the [ON CONFLICT clause](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/insert#on-conflict-clause), as well as the SQLite compatible INSERT OR REPLACE/INSERT OR IGNORE syntax.

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> ... ON CONFLICT <optional_columns_list> <optional_where_clause> DO NOTHING | DO UPDATE SET column_name = <optional 'excluded.' qualifier> column_name, ... <optional_where_clause>;
```

Examples:

```
insert into tbl VALUES (3,5,1) ON CONFLICT (i) WHERE k < 5 DO UPDATE SET k = 1;

-- shorter syntax
-- assuming tbl has a primary key/unique constraint, do nothing on conflict
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tbl(i) VALUES(1);
-- or update the table with the new values instead
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tbl(i) VALUES(1);
```

However there are still few [limitations listed here](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/pull/5866).

Comment: Batch insertion is not supported in combination with ON CONFLICT.